# can I write the below query using Over()in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, sqlalchemy

I am trying to optimise the below sql query but am not finding any way to do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(followers.follower_id)
    FROM
      followers
    WHERE
      followers.follow_start_date <= dates.start_date
  ) AS running_total
, dates.onboarded_date
FROM
   followers
   RIGHT JOIN
   (
     select distinct
       follow_start_date as start_date
     from
       followers
     where
       follow_start_date <= "2020-10-01"
   ) dates
     ON followers.follow_start_date = dates.start_date
ORDER BY
  dates.start_date
;
```

the above query gives me a running total of followers on day basis. So I am first getting list of unique start dates from table and joining the query that counts followers up until given day.

it gives me output like below:

```
running_total,start_date

498,2020-08-14 00:00:00

499,2020-08-17 00:00:00

500,2020-09-04 00:00:00

503,2020-09-30 00:00:00
```

any help to optimise this above query or write the query in a better way to get the same result is appreciated.

Edit:
explain query output:

```
1,PRIMARY,followers,,ALL,,,,,926,100,Using temporary; Using filesort
1,PRIMARY,<derived3>,,ref,<auto_key0>,<auto_key0>,6,follower_app.followers.follow_start_date,10,100,Using index
3,DERIVED,followers,,ALL,,,,,926,33.33,Using where; Using temporary
2,DEPENDENT SUBQUERY,followers,,ALL,,,,,926,3.33,Using where
```

A better way in mysql or sqlalchemy would be perfect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115643/discussion-between-andriy-m-and-user1795999).

Answer (score 1):

You know how an owl can turn its head almost completely around?  That's what happens to me when I see a `RIGHT JOIN`.  Is this a correct rewrite of your query, using `LEFT JOIN`?

```
SELECT  (fs.follow_start_date <= ds.start_date) AS running_total ,
        ds.onboarded_date
    FROM (
        SELECT  distinct follow_start_date as start_date
        from  followers AS fs
        where  follow_start_date <= "2020-10-01" 
         ) dates AS ds
    LEFT JOIN  followers AS fs  ON fs.follow_start_date = ds.start_date
    ORDER BY  ds.start_date;
```

For performance, that needs

```
followers:  INDEX(follow_start_date)
dates:  INDEX(start_date)
```

Hmmm... Something seems to be missing for `running_total`.

Comment: no its not right. it doesnt have to be a right join... its works the same even with just join

Comment: Now that the original query has been fixed, you may want to revise your answer.

Comment: If "use OVER()" is the important part, I don't have an answer.  In any case, `INDEX(follow_start_date)` is important.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer:

```
select distinct date(follow_start_date), count(followers) over ( order by  follow_start_date)
 from followers 
where 
 follow_start_date <='2020-10-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be the running total you are after:

```
SELECT
      SUM(COUNT(f.follower_id)) OVER (ORDER BY f.follow_start_date)
          AS running_total,
      f.follow_start_date AS onboarded_date
FROM
      followers AS f
WHERE
      f.follow_start_date <= '2020-10-01'
GROUP BY
      f.follow_start_date
ORDER BY
      f.follow_start_date
;
```